# How do I receive push notifications of new Outlook emails to an Android device?

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm making an Android app in which I want user to sign in to their Outlook account and receive push notifications to the app from the Microsoft Graph API when an email is received in their inbox. How can I do this?

I can subscribe to inbox changes using a HTTP subscription request (as specified here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0), with something like:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": 
  "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/notificationClient",
  "resource": "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime": "2016-03-20T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

In this request I need to specify a "notificationUrl" where notification updates are sent to - how can I set this up? Is there functionality for this on Azure?

From there I believe I can use the instructions here to send push notifications to the Android device https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started.

This involves setting up a notification hub on Azure which connects to Firebase, which then sends notifications the app. Is this the best/only way to do this?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: If my answer helpful please mark it as answer by clicking beside the checkbox of your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The notificationUrl can be the webhook url of the azure function app. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/create-a-web-hook-or-api-azure-function/.

Therefore, you can use azure function to invoke Firebase API to send notifications.

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs#packages---functions-1x and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1.

Besides, I would recommend you to use azure logic app. It has built in connector to use when a message arrives your inbox.

Take a look here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook.